# Change of basis matrix for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've already asked this question here, but theres a misconception about the phrase "change of basis matrix from B to C", and I think the answers were given in the inverse of what's in my book.

So, in my book, the change of basis matrix from $B$ to $C$ is the matrix $M$ such that

$$[ \ \ \ ]_B = M[\ \ \ ]_C$$

where $M$ has the vectors $c_1,c_2$ of the base $C$ written as a linear combination of the basis $B$.

So, the question is:

> The change of basis matrix from $B = \{1+t, 1-t^2\}$ to the base $C  = \{c_1, c_2\}$
>   is:
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}\color{Red}{1} & \color{Blue}{2}\\\color{Red}{1} &
>  \color{Blue}{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Find basis $C$.

So what I did was:

$$c_1 = \color{Red}{1}(1+t) + \color{Red}{1}(1-t^2) = 2 + t -t^2\\c_2 = \color{Blue}{2}(1+t) \color{Blue}{-1}(1-t^2) = 1 + 2t + t^2$$

Am I rigth?

Comment: Not quite; $c_1$ and $c_2$ should be multiplied by $\frac13$, and the end of your computation for $c_2$ is wrong.

Comment: @Bernard why 1/3?

Comment: When you compute $M^{-1}$, there's a factor $\frac13$. Actually,  $M^{-1}=\frac13M$,

Comment: @Bernard why I need to compute $M^{-1}$? I've already found $c_1$ and $c_2$. Are you using the definition I have in the exercise? Thank you!

Comment: But if $M$ has $c_1$ and $c_2$ expressed with $b_1$ and $b_2$, $M^{-1}$, which is the change of base matrix from $\mathcal C$ to  $\mathcal B$ has $b_1$ and $b_2$ expressed with $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: @Bernard I've found that there is a difference in definition in literature around the world. Here, in Brazil, when they say "change of basis matrix from $B$ to $C$", this matrix has vectors of $C$ (in each column) written as l.c. of $B$. In this definition, I did the rigth procedure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20742/discussion-between-bernard-and-guerlando-ocs).

Comment: "You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq."

Comment: OK. Your convention for change of basis matrices is the same as mine. For the rest, Im sorry, I misunderstood your problem – I thought it was the following: you're given the basis $\mathcal C$ and the change of basis matrix from $ \mathcal B$ to  $\mathcal C$. Find  $\mathcal B$.

Comment: @Bernard no problem. Thank you by your attention! So I did the rigth thing?

Comment: Absolutely. I'll try to read carefully (it's late here in France…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered in comments.  Moving to community wiki so it doesn't hang around forever in an unanswered state.